# why my MySQL queries executed before PHP Conditional check?

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I'm learning to create conditional event where sql checkout data where is exists before inserting data so they don't conflicted.

i've tried using mysql row check in php then check if query empty before i tried to validate the query executed properly.

also trying to close db connection when conditional satisfied but it worthless anyway.

```php
$user = addslashes(strtolower($usr));
$mail = addslashes(strtolower($mail));
$pass = md5(addslashes($pwd));

$check = $db->query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                   FROM `users`
                                   WHERE LOWER(`username`) = LOWER('$user')
                                      OR LOWER(`email`) = LOWER('$mail'))");

if (!$check) {
    $db->close();
    return false;
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`)
                   VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$mail')";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    $db->close();
    return true;
}
```

I'm expecting it execute my queries while data was empty and return false while data has been existed.

Comment: `var_dump($check)` gives what? You should not use `addslashes` nor `md5`. Parameterize your query and use `password_hash` (and `password_verify` where needed).

Comment: also to add to @user3783243 's comment this method/approach is also prone to race conditions.. If you want to prevent duplicates you should be adding a unique key to the table (also)..

Comment: @user3783243 it look something like this `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: i think, `username` and `email` both fields using as unique values? right, then why are you using `OR` condition here?

Comment: *"i think, username and email both fields using as unique values? right, then why are you using OR condition here?"* @devpro some applications allow signin on a username OR email..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: agreed, but here checking existing, i think these two values should be unique for any user? may i am wrong. but OP using 2 diff values in 2 columns, not 1 value with 2 columns by using OR, i think AND is more secure option

Comment: Depends entirely on the application. Can separate users have the same username or the same email? Or is it just the combination that's unique? I would say the email is at least supposed to be unique, but again - depends on what the application does and what the structure is.

Comment: yes i see your point also @devpro it seams a bit wierd.. Also we don't know the rest of the code / process.. Maybe the application allows multiple users with the same emailaddress and the user / email combination will be verified after with a email link clicking..

Comment: yes agreed with @Qirel: unique email is enough, but if OP using both then, i am just adding my suggestion... but its good and healthy discussion.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that `$check` will always be a truthy value, so long as the query never fails. If the query returns 0 rows, it is still a true object.

You should instead check if there were any values returned. You can also simplify the query quite a bit, given that MySQL is case-insensitive, and you don't need to check if the result exists. Using a prepared statement, the code would look like this

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $usr, $mail);
$stmt->execute();
$check = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close(); 

// True if the user exists 
if ($check) { 
    return false;
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(" INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, LOWER(?))");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $usr, $pass, $mail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

That said, you should not use `md5()` for passwords - use `password_hash()` with `password_verify()` instead.

Comment: keep in mind that this is still prone to race conditions, assuming there is non unique key in the table..

Comment: Fair point - you can use use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=username` or something along those lines, then check what the affected rows were, or possibly the inserted ID.

Comment: Indeed it would. Quite assumptious of me really, we haven't seen any tablestructure posted with the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code like this

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `users`
    WHERE LOWER(`username`) = LOWER('$user')
    OR LOWER(`email`) = LOWER('$mail'))");


$check = $conn->query($sql); 
$value = $check->fetch_row()[0];
if($value > 0 ){    
    echo "existed".$value; // you can change accordingly
}else{
    echo "doesn't exist"; // this also
}
```

Because database respond the query in 1 for exist and 0 for non-exist so the num_row will be always 1 thats why we cant determine the existence with num_row so we have to fetch the value.

Comment: it gain error `Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$num_row`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: try updated code. I have checked on my database also.It will surely run.